# Microsoft Visual Studio console asking for dotnet sdk even if it is installed

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

I've installed Microsoft .NET Core SDK with Visual Studio 2019 but whenever I am debugging an Azure function, the debug console is asking to install the dotnet sdk:

[[image]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMMy0.png)

[[image]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO9Kq.png)

Comment: What is the version of your azure function? v1, v2 or v3?

Comment: I am using v2(Core 2.1) and not 2.2

Comment: hm - just speculating here - is the `dotnet` command available?

Comment: Yes dotnet command is available

Comment: Please notice that azure function v2 is based on .Net core 2.2. But you havent install it.

Answer (score 0):

Azure function v2 is based on .Net core 2.2.

[image]

Have a look of this document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#languages

Comment: Console giving same error for 3.0(With core 3.1) azure functions so I don't think so the issue is related to installation but I'll try

Comment: @user3026700 So if you go to `C:\Users\vjade1\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.50.0\cli_x64` and run `func` you will face this problem?

Comment: I tried running func.exe from the location mentioned above and it is running. I can even attach the debugger explicitly but whenever I am triggering the function through VS19 it is giving me the message to install dotnet sdk